# Why does the metric system use the Celsius scale rather than the Fahrenheit scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, history, metrology

Part of why I ask this is because the Fahrenheit scale has a higher degree of precision than the Celsius scale. And the Kelvin scale could just as easily been adapted to be an extension of the Fahrenheit scale(absolute zero is -459.67 degrees Fahrenheit).

Comment: Why do you think that Fahrenheit is more precise than Celsius (or Kelvin)? And Rankine is the extension of Fahrenheit.

Comment: 1 degree celsius = 1.8 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: 1.0 degree Celsius = 1.8 degrees Fahrenheit (exactly). There is no loss of precision.

Comment: I think @Mr X meant that the Fahrenheit degree is smaller (180 degrees between BP and FP of water as opposed to Celsius and Kelvin which have 100 degrees ) so it therefore might be considered a more precise scale. That's what makes it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what is called *the metric system* defines degrees Celcius as the default temperature unit anymore. At least, if you by *the metric system* mean *the SI unit system*, then the (former) base temperature unit is **kelvin**, $\mathrm{K}$, and not degree Celsius, $\mathrm{^\circ C}$.

Both **degree Fahrenheit**, $\mathrm{^\circ F}$, and **degree Celcius**, $\mathrm{^\circ C}$, (as well as **degree Rankine**, $\mathrm{^\circ R}$, and **degree Rømer**, $\mathrm{^\circ Rø}$ as well as other local or past temperature units) are exactly defined from the kelvin scale. There is no "loss in precision" by using one unit instead of another - meaning, you can always convert from one unit to the other without "losing" precision in the number. They are defined in various ways - ways that feel odd for some and intuitive for others - but are nevertheless all equally valid.

Typically, whenever the *the metric system* or *the mks system* is mentioned, it typically refers to the modern SI system. But it wasn't always so since the unit systems have undergone quite a clean-up over the centuries. Back in the late 1700s' France where what was called *the metric system* was invented and defined for the first time, there were a few differences from what we today know as the SI unit system. For instance, *volume* (then called *capacity*) was back then originally given the default unit **litre**, $\mathrm{L}$, which does not match the (former) SI base unit for volume today which is the **cubicmetre**, $\mathrm{m^3}$. I'm not entirely sure, but it is possible that also the default temperature unit back then was originally defined as degree Celcius, $\mathrm{^\circ C}$. This might be the reason that it is still here and there seen as the default nowadays even though it is an outdated base definition when comparing to SI.

In general when doing scientific work I would advise you to always use SI units by default and never think about it with the term "metric system" so as to avoid ambiguity. So, as long as you don't have specific reasons to go with something else, just go for the kelvin, $\mathrm{K}$, by default for temperature. (Certain scientific fields work in some specific sets of non-SI units per tradition or of practical reasons - such as within chemistry. You might also have local reasons to stick with non-SI units, of course - the Americans and the Brits might never let go of their imperial system...).

Comment: mmHg is a temperature unit?

Comment: @NobertSchuch Oh my, no, I have mistakenly included a pressure unit... Thanks for pointing it out. It has been removed from the answer.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1923/

Answer (score 3):

If by metric you mean [Système international (d'unités)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) then $\mathrm{^\circ C}$ is not, at least formally, part of it. It's [derived unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Derived_units) that has unique properties that makes it so popular.

First: for temperature gradient $\Delta T$ of $1\mathrm{K} = 1\mathrm{^\circ C}$ which makes calculations so much easier as it's one to one identical, only shifted 273,15 degrees.

Second: it's so much more natural to think in Celsius terms where zero is point of freezing and cold and 100 of boiling and burning hot, where with Fahrenheit is 32 and 212 which is almost absolutely illogical.

Comment: The 0 and 100 points on the F scale really are peculiar to the extent that no one really seems certain of the origin.  I've never understood the attraction of Farenheit to people compared to the intuitively friendly Celsius scale.

Comment: Well, 32 is a nice power of 2. And $212-32=180$, which is appropriate for something measured in degrees. As I recently said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44126/16685), people have been using sexagesimal notation to represent fractional quantities since the 3rd millennium BC. European mathematicians continued to use sexagesimal for recording and computing with fractional quantities up to the late 17th century, but it was gradually displaced by decimal fractions. The Fahrenheit scale is from the early 18th century.

Comment: BTW, I'm *not* trying to promote the Fahrenheit scale. I learned it as a young child, but in Australia we [switched to Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_Australia#Metrication_of_weather_reporting_and_forecasts) in the early 1970s, around the time I started high school.

Comment: Decimal notation is older than you state, and more natural too. Romans used decimals in their Roman numbers: I for units, X for tens, C for hundreds, M for thousands. Real numbers with decimal separator (`,` or `.`) since its indian invention, arabic spread, and european development. Where do you see prevalence of sexagesimal system?

Comment: The Roman numeral system is not a positional notation. The Hindu-Arabic decimal system was popularised in Europe by Fibonacci in [Liber Abaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Abaci) (1202), but the use of a decimal separator for fractional quantities came much later.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin#Decimal_fractions) "Muslim mathematicians were the first to utilize decimals instead of fractions on a large scale. Al-Kashi's book, Key to Arithmetic, was written at the beginning of the 15th century and was the stimulus for the systematic application of decimals to whole numbers and fractions thereof".

Comment: Simon Stevin introduced a system of notation for decimal fractions in 1585, but "His notation is rather unwieldy. The point separating the integers from the decimal fractions seems to be the invention of Bartholomaeus Pitiscus, in whose trigonometrical tables (1612) it occurs and it was accepted by John Napier in his logarithmic papers (1614 and 1619)."

Comment: As quoted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal#cite_note-11), Newton mentioned the use of sexagesimal for calculation in the 1670s.

Comment: Yes, Romans' numerals were not positional but were decimal nevertheless. And if Newton was using sexagesimal numerals where are those 60 digits?